# How to use event handling method in Angular 5?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

I'm totally new to Angular 5. In my application there's a Google map. When a user zooms in or zooms out , I need to catch that action and do a task. There's already a zoom change event in Google API. How do I use that function inside Angular 5?

I want to use this

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
  var zoom = this.map.getZoom();
  if (zoom > 3) {

    console.log("Zoom changed to high")
  } else {

    console.log("Zoom changed to low")
  } 
})
```

I tried it with in ngOnInit as well. Then I'm getting google is not defined. 
My appcomponent look like this.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @ViewChild(HeatmapLayer) heatmapLayer: HeatmapLayer;
  heatmap: google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer;
  map: google.maps.Map;
  points = [];

  ngOnInit() {

    this.heatmapLayer['initialized$'].subscribe(heatmap => {
      this.points = [

        new google.maps.LatLng(7.8731, 80.7718),
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.8631, 80.7618),
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.8531, 80.758),
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.8431, 80.7418),
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.8331, 80.7318),
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.8231, 80.7218),
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.8131, 80.7118),
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.8111, 80.7018),
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.8105, 80.6918),
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.8100, 80.6518),
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.9403, 81.0188),
        new google.maps.LatLng(7.9803, 83.0188),

      ];
      this.heatmap = heatmap;
      this.map = this.heatmap.getMap();
      this.heatmap.set('opacity',0.6)
    });


  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, did you tried this code in `ngOnint` ? it's better to try as many possibilities and come with your failures. so it makes easy to track.

Comment: @ k11k2 - Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already added google map script in index.html

You need to declare google variable like below:

```
<!-- After all imports -->

declare var google:any;
```

Then you can use :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'zoom_changed',()=> {
   //Code here   
})
```

Comment: Yes I have already added that. But I'm getting the error I'm getting google is not defined. I have included that in ngOnInit.

Comment: @kavish Please read answer you need to define `declare var google:any;` in your component.ts after all import lines.

Comment: Yes. I did that too when I'm trying your answer

Comment: @kavish Ok great can you try executing that code after set 3 sec timeout ? may be google map script is not initialized when ngOnInit runs.

Comment: Can you please help me with that @Javascript Hupp Technologies

Comment: Ok you are getting google undefined at line 6 : `heatmap: google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer;` right ?

Comment: Not there. I'm getting that in  google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

Comment: Can you please check

Comment: Can you show your code how you added event listener in ngOnInit.

Comment: can you try this code in `ngAfterViewInit()` method ?